# Scala quasiquote concatenation

Tags: scala, scala-macros, scala-quasiquotes

I'm new to scala macros and I spent a couple of days trying to write my very first one.
I have a problem with quasiquotes concatenation.

There is a list of case clauses, let's say the following:

```
val cases = cq"x => 1 " :: cq"_ => 0 " :: Nil
```

And I need to build a **partial function** from it. 
The problem is that I don't have an idea how to paste them in the final quasiquote.
The documentation says I should do something like this:

```
q"{ case ..$cases }"
```

but it doesn't work if I do so.

Is there a way to build a PartialFunction from such a list?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I believe this is correct approach. What error you have exactly?

Comment: Also your pattern is bit strange `x => 1` mathes any expression, if you are referencing to some local value named `x` you should use  `\`x\` => 1` as patern

Comment: The error is the following: exception during macro expansion: 
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: scala.collection.immutable.List(case (x @ _) => 1, case _ => 0) is not valid representation of pattern match case.

Comment: Are you using Scala 2.10 or 2.11?

Comment: My pattern doesn't make any sense now, I just took something very simple.

Comment: Scala version is 2.11

Comment: And it works if I write like this:

val case1 = cq"x => 1 "
val case2 = cq"_ => 0 "

val tree = q""" {
  case $case1
  case $case2
  } """

Comment: Can you please provide more details. I can't really reproduce the issue on 2.11.6. https://gist.github.com/densh/377df69df170fa205f3b

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following works for me with 2.11.2:

```
import scala.reflect.macros.Context
object Macros {
    def partial: PartialFunction[Int, Int] = macro partialImpl
    def partialImpl(c: Context): c.Expr[PartialFunction[Int, Int]]= {
        import c.universe._
        val cases = cq"x => 1 " :: cq"_ => 0 " :: Nil
        val pf = q"{ case ..$cases } : PartialFunction[Int, Int]"
        c.Expr[PartialFunction[Int, Int]](pf)

    }
}
```

Then you can call `Macros.partial(1)`, for example, or `Macros.partial.isDefinedAt(2)`.

Note that in order to make this work, I had to explicitly use `PartialFunction[Int, Int]` in the quasiquote `q"{ case ..$cases } : PartialFunction[Int, Int]"`.  It didn't work without the explicit type definition (it otherwise assumes `PartialFunction[Any, Int]`).

[Here](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/quasiquotes/expression-details.html#partial-function) is the specification for quasiquote Syntax for partial functions.  It works as a pure syntax tree, but apparently cannot be interpreted as a typed expression except `PartialFunction[Any, T]` by a macro unless the type is made explicit.

Comment: Pattern matching anon funcs can be Function or PartialFunction depending on the expected type.

Comment: Your code has a bug: `PartialFunction[Int, Int]{ case ... }` will create a PartialFunction that is defined on the whole domain. What you want is instead `{ case ... }: PartialFunction[Int, Int]`